# Возможно ли поставить запятую перед двоеточием?

Tags: пунктуация

Он описывал на примере танца дождя, исполняемого индейцами Хопи, обитавших на южной территории современных Соединенных Штатов Америки (Нью-Мексико): индейцы племени верили, что ритуальный танец вызовет дождь, который был необходим их полям.

Answer (score 2):

<....>современных Соединенных Штатов Америки (Нью-Мексико)***,*** : - если так,то  нет, такое в русском языке не возможно!

Comment: Я бы сказала невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

В пунктуации отсутствует сочетание знаков «запятая-двоеточие».  Если после обособленного оборота следует двоеточие, то оно поглощает запятую, закрывающую оборот.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Из трех основных знаков (запятая, тире, двоеточие) свободно сочетаются тире и запятая. При оформлении прямой речи возможно сочетание "двоеточие-тире", например: "Я скоро уезжаю", - сказал он и добавил: - Может быть, завтра".